# what is the confirmation section in the block info?

Tags: blockchain, block, confirmations

in the details of a bitcoin block there's a section called block confirmation (which is different than transaction confirmation), first i thought it was the number of the blocks that are created after this block but there is a lot of blocks that has one confirmation with a great number of blocks after them, i would appreciate it if you can tell me how does that work?
this is a an important research for me, if you don't have any information about the matter please vote for my question so i can get an answer, thank you.
[image: this is an example]

Comment: This seems like a bug in whatever blockchain explorer you're using, try a different one. Your explanation of confirmations is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **in the details of a bitcoin block there's a section called block confirmation**

The details of what is in a block *as transmitted between Bitcoin nodes* is shown at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation and other places. In the Bitcoin network, there's no item "block confirmation" that counts block confirmations.

> ### Block Headers
>
> Block headers are sent in a headers packet in response to a getheaders message.
>
> | Field Size | Description | Data type | Comments |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 4 | version | int32_t | Block version information (note, this is signed) |
> | 32 | prev_block | char[32] | The hash value of the previous block this particular block references |
> | 32 | merkle_root | char[32] | The reference to a Merkle tree collection which is a hash of all transactions related to this block |
> | 4 | timestamp | uint32_t | A timestamp recording when this block was created (Will overflow in 2106[2]) |
> | 4 | bits | uint32_t | The calculated difficulty target being used for this block |
> | 4 | nonce | uint32_t | The nonce used to generate this block… to allow variations of the header and compute different hashes |
> | 1+ | txn_count | var_int | Number of transaction entries, this value is always 0 |

**Many websites that display blockchain data add extra items of their own invention**. For example, when looking at a transaction, some websites show a sending address even though this is not present in the actual transaction data as transmitted between nodes.

This "block confirmation" count may be something of this sort. To find out what it means you have to ask the support team at that specific website.

Comment: thank you, you've been a huge help.